# How to use a javascript instance in jquery/Select a javascript handle via jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As a jquery-beginner, i should bind a javascript object into my jquery functions, like:

```
<div title="StackOverflow" onclick="javascript:action(this)">Content</div>
```

and in action i will handle the "this" :

```
function action(instance){
example=instance.attr("title");
}
```

but the "instance" is not a jquery object so i can't work with it. The syntax

```
example=$(instance).attr("title");
```

doesn't help me either.

I'd be glad of any suggestions

Comment: you dont need to put javascript: on onclick.

Comment: using action($(this)) works too, the "instance" parameter is from there a jQuery object. It remains a bad practice anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function action(instance){
                example=$(instance).attr("title");
                alert(example);
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a id="test" title="StackOverflow" onclick="javascript:action(this)" href="#">Content</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using jQuery then you should completely separate the definition of your HTML and associated JavaScript.  For example

HTML:

```
<div id="soDiv" title="StackOverflow">Content</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#soDiv').click(function() {
    var example = $(this).attr('title');
    ...
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// HTML file
<div title="StackOverflow" id="stackoverflow">Content</div>
// JS File
document.getElementById("stackoverflow").addEventListener("click", function () {
  var example = this.getAttribute("title");
});
```

[Seperations of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div title="StackOverflow" id="stack">Content</div>
```

Javascript (with jQuery):

```
$('#stack').click(function(){
    alert(this.title);
});
```